# Ошибка в bash-скрипте

Tags: bash

Есть такой код:

```
while :
do
    if [ "pidof python2 run.py | wc -w" = null ]; then
            echo "python2 run.py not running, starting"
            /home/aos/run_server.sh &
    else
            echo "running"
    fi
    sleep 12000
done
```

Ошибка такая:

> **./check.sh:** строка 10: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным
>   маркером «done» ./check.sh: строка 10: `done'

Comment: В условии написано что-то странное

Comment: 1. [миелофон вкл.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dos2unix). 2. строки 4 и 5 **никогда** не выполнятся.

Comment: WTF *null* в этом коде?

Answer (score 1):

результатом `wc -w` будет числовое значение, оно не может быть сравнено указанным вами способом `=` с строковым значением `null`. В вашем случае нужно использовать, конструкцию `-eq 0`. К тому-же вы в условии ставите 2-е константы, тоесть выражение

`"pidof python2 run.py | wc -w"` так и останется строкой

`pidof python2 run.py | wc -w`.

Для того, чтобы это выражение выдало результат, используйте

`$(pidof python2 run.py | wc -w)`.

В общем итоге ваше условие, как я его понял, должно выглядеть следующим образом:

`if [ "$(pidof python2 run.py | wc -w)" -eq 0 ]; then`

Более того, мне кажется целесообразние, в вашем случае, использовать условие:

```
if [ -z "$(pidof python2 run.py)" ]; then
```